# Kendo UI how to change dropDownList to text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Once I create dropdown list from existing text field input in Kendo UI - is there a way of changing it back to text field?

```
$('#myInput').kendoDropDownList({...});
```

I wish to have something like:

```
var kendolist =  $('#myInput').kendoDropDownList({...});
kendolist.textField({....});
```

or

```
kendolist.destroy().textField({....});
```

at best without extensive jQuery shenanigans...  :)

Comment: What about having both created bound to the same data and showing one or the other depending on what you want? Then you only have to play with visibility...

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I'll try it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible to turn it back into regular textbox. You can use the [destoy](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-destroy) method of the widget, however there will be some HTML left which you will not really need and you will need to do some manually cleaning with JavaScript.

Better destroy the widget and remove all the HTML then add regular textbox manually.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of knew that. I was just hoping or curious if there is something nicer. But thanks.